# Buttons stop working after changing state in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I've setup a login system. After switching states to either the forgotPassword page or the create account page then pressing the backbutton, all buttons on the mainpage are no longer responsive. The

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from MainScreenGUI import Ui_MainWindow
from forgotPasswordGUI import ForgotPasswordWindow
from createAccountGUI import CreateAccountWindow

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.createAccountButton.clicked.connect(self.show_create_account_window)
        self.ui.forgotPasswordButton.clicked.connect(self.show_forgot_password_window)

    def show_create_account_window(self):
        self.create_account_window = CreateAccountWindow()
        self.create_account_window.setupUi(self, self)  # Pass the MainWindow instance
        self.setCentralWidget(self.create_account_window.centralwidget)

    def show_forgot_password_window(self):
        self.forgot_password_window = ForgotPasswordWindow(self)
        self.forgot_password_window.setupUi(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.forgot_password_window.centralwidget)

    def go_back_to_main_screen(self):
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

forgotPasswordGUI.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from MainScreenGUI import Ui_MainWindow

class ForgotPasswordWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window  

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        {text box/label code}

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(699, 500, 521, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 40, 40))
        self.backButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("../Images/back_arrow.png"))  
        self.backButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.backButton.setObjectName("backButton")
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.goBack)  
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reset Password"))

    def goBack(self):
        self.main_window.go_back_to_main_screen()
```

MainScreenGUI.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        
        {text box/label code}
        
        self.forgotPasswordButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.forgotPasswordButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1019, 489, 202, 40))
        self.forgotPasswordButton.setObjectName("forgotPasswordButton")
        
        self.createAccountButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.createAccountButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 489, 202, 40))
        self.createAccountButton.setObjectName("createAccountButton")
        
        self.loginButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.loginButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 550, 521, 41))
        self.loginButton.setObjectName("loginButton")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textEdit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))  
        self.textEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))  
        self.forgotPasswordButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Forgot Password"))
        self.createAccountButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create an Account"))
        self.loginButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))
```

Ive tried changing how the ui is setup and rewritten parts of the code but i still get the same error.

Comment: Do not change `setCentralWidget()` to "switch" between pages. Use QStackedWidget.

Comment: Post a [mre] with debugging details. Anyway, you should reconnect signal handlers for buttons in the ```go_back_to_main_screen()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not modify the code generated by *Qt Designer* but create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

> [**QStackedWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html) Class
>
> The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


# from MainScreenGUI import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
#        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
#        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
#        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        
#        {text box/label code}
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.forgotPasswordButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.forgotPasswordButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1019, 489, 202, 40))
        self.forgotPasswordButton.setObjectName("forgotPasswordButton")
        
        self.createAccountButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.createAccountButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 489, 202, 40))
        self.createAccountButton.setObjectName("createAccountButton")
        
        self.loginButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.loginButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 550, 521, 41))
        self.loginButton.setObjectName("loginButton")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
# ?        self.textEdit_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))  
# ?        self.textEdit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))  
        self.forgotPasswordButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Forgot Password"))
        self.createAccountButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create an Account"))
        self.loginButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Login"))
        
        
#from forgotPasswordGUI import ForgotPasswordWindow
class ForgotPasswordWindow(object):
# ?    def __init__(self, main_window):
# ?        self.main_window = main_window  

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
#        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
#        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
#        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

#        {text box/label code}

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(699, 500, 521, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 40, 40))
        self.backButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Ok.png"))  
        self.backButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.backButton.setObjectName("backButton")
# ?        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.goBack)  
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reset Password"))

# ?    def goBack(self):
# ?        self.main_window.go_back_to_main_screen()

# !!! +++
class MyForgotPasswordWindow(QMainWindow, ForgotPasswordWindow):            # !!! +++
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        

#from createAccountGUI import CreateAccountWindow
class CreateAccountWindow(QMainWindow):                                    # !!! +++
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget) 

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel() 
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("CreateAccountWindow")
        self.label.setStyleSheet('''
            #label {
                font-size: 30px;
                color: #FF4500;
            }
        ''')
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.back_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back_button.setObjectName("back_button")
        self.back_button.setText("<- Back")
        

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

# !!! +++
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):                                             # !!! +++
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.myMainWindow = MyMainWindow()                                  # !!! +++
        self.createAccountWindow = CreateAccountWindow()                    # !!! +++
        self.myForgotPasswordWindow = MyForgotPasswordWindow()              # !!! +++

        self.stack = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)                         # !!! +++
        self.ix_stack_1 = self.stack.addWidget(self.myMainWindow)
        self.ix_stack_2 = self.stack.addWidget(self.createAccountWindow)
        self.ix_stack_3 = self.stack.addWidget(self.myForgotPasswordWindow)
        
        self.myMainWindow.createAccountButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.myMainWindow.forgotPasswordButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2))
            
        self.createAccountWindow.back_button.clicked.connect(                # +++
            lambda : self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.myForgotPasswordWindow.backButton.clicked.connect(              # +++
            lambda : self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0))

        self.QVBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.QVBlayout.addWidget(self.stack)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(1920, 1080)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

[image]